# Magento - Custom Layout Update

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

Im just trying to find a google reference source for Magento Custom layout updates done on category and product pages and would be really grateful to receive a few different links or books names.

I needs to be layout updates as I have very limited access to our template files etc.

Version: Magento community running both VU1.7 and 1.8 on different instances.

Answer (score 0):

Change your hoster, work process, admin, whatever avoids that you can't access your template files. Doing custom layout updates on whatever level is a lot slower than just changing templates and layout xml files.

Beside this, you are talking about category and product layout xml changes?

You can add whatever XML code in the textareas you want, starting with `<reference>`. I have no clue what happens if you start with `<block>`, though :-)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19804688/magento-category-custom-layout-update-to-set-new-product-list-template-is-not

Comment: Sadly the limitation is the company ive just started working for signed a very tight 3 year contract with a large development company which does not allow us access to the template files etc until the period is over else it violates our support agreement. currently the dev agency quotes between 4-8 hours for simple template changes even when I supply them with the code...

Comment: Sounds like, even if you pay the fine and go out of the contract you win ;-)

Comment: I disagree. As an agency I would *usually* not give the merchant direct access to their templates to mess around with them as well. But this sounds more like a communication problem. Maybe the template changes are not *that* simple? Maybe they follow a strict QA and deployment process? That and the PM overhead costs time for any change, as simple as it may be. Requesting/implementing multiple small changes at once would probably be much less expensive.

Comment: You are right. I'm always looking from the perspective as a developer. And want to do everything by myself. But there must still be a way that a customer is able to change his code. A few of my customers change their live code, everything is in git and as long as the accountability is clear (it is the customers, not the agency) there should be no problem.